# Evaluate the integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{3x}-\mathrm{e}^{x}}{x\left(\mathrm{e}^{3x}+1\right)\left(\mathrm{e}^{x}+1\right)} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having trouble with any of the "extreme" integrals from the 2006 MIT Integration Bee.

Evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{3x}-\mathrm{e}^{x}}{x\left(\mathrm{e}^{3x}+1\right)\left(\mathrm{e}^{x}+1\right)} \, dx$$

The final answer given was: $\frac{1}{2}\ln(3)$

Comment: What have you tried? Series? Calculus of residues?

Comment: @HansEngler Using series expansions of the terms in the denominator results in a formidable double series.  Using contour integration might be tractable after using Feynman's trick (I haven't looked at this closely enough to determine its feasability).  But both of those approaches seem to be inefficient in comparison to recognizing that this is effectively a Frullani integral in disguise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is simply a [Frullani integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral) with $f(x)=\frac{1}{e^x+1}$, $a=1$, and $b=3$.

Noting $f(0)=\frac12$ and $f(\infty)=0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{3x}-e^x}{x(e^{3x}+1)(e^x+1)}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{(e^{3x}+1)-(e^x+1))}{x(e^{3x}+1)(e^x+1)}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\frac1{e^x+1}-\frac1{e^{3x}+1}}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12\log(3)
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: @user398843 What steps would be required?  Are you familiar with Frullani's Integral?  If not, I suggest you click on the link that I embedded in the first sentence of the posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

An elementary approach:

By parts (since $\frac{1}{e^x+1}-\frac{1}{e^{3x}+1}\sim_{0^+} x/2$):
$$
I=\int_0^{\infty}\log(x)\left(\frac{e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}-3\frac{e^{3 x}}{(e^{3 x}+1)^2}\right)=J(1)-J(3)
$$

Now Substitute $3x = y $ into last integral and we get

$$
J(3)=-\log(3)\int_0^{\infty}dy\frac{e^y}{(e^y+1)^2}+J(1)=-\frac{\log(3)}{2}+J(1)
$$

or

> $$
> I=J(1)+\frac{\log(3)}{2}-J(1)=\frac{\log(3)}{2}
> $$

Note that of course this approach works also if we replace $1\rightarrow a$ and $3\rightarrow b$ ($a,b>0$) in the exponentials

Comment: IBP is one way of proving "Frullani" when the "$f(x)$" satisfies additional conditions.